# AVCaptureSession hides buttons in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I'm new to Swift and I'm trying to create a custom camera.

I've been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=994Hsi1zs6Q) tutorial and my problem is that the camera layer hides buttons that I've inserted on the storyboard.

**Code:**

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080

        let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
        var error: NSError?

        do {
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)

            if (error == nil && captureSession?.canAddInput(input) != nil) {

                captureSession?.addInput(input)

                stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
                stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                if (captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) != nil) {
                    captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

                    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                    previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
                    previewLayer?.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                    cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)
                    captureSession?.startRunning()   
                }
            }
        } catch {    
        }
    }
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Try inserting the previewLayer at index zero `cameraView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)` instead of just adding the layer.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try change the hierarchy of your view in storyboard. And make sure that your `button` comes after the `Camera View` in the view hierarchy.

```
ViewController
   - Top Layout Guide
   - Bottom Layout Guide
   - View
     - Camera View
     - Button 
   - First Responder
   - Exit
```